# Slicing in a list element of string and also in each character of the list element

Tags: python, for-loop, slice

I have the following code code:

```
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']
index = 0
for name in people:
    print(name, '\n')
    name1 = name
    for name in name1:
        print(name1[index], end =' ')
        if name[index] < name1[index]:
            index = index + 1
        else:
            break
```

I want to slice on a list of elements of string and also in each character of the list element selected. Using only for in in python

This is the result I got:

Vianney

V Mariana

M Ignacio

I Gaspar

G

and, I want this:

Vianney

V i a n n e y

from each element

Comment: You have not shown the definition of `people`.  We cannot run this code.

Comment: people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']                                                
index = 0
for name in people:
    print(name, '\n')
    name1 = name
    for name in name1:
        print(name1[index], end =' ')
        if name[index] < name1[index]:
            index = index + 1
        else:
            break

Comment: The first is `for name in people: print(name, "\n", *name)` you could also use two print statements. Not a double for-loop

Comment: There's many issues with your code. For one, you probably meant index instead of ndex. It's unclear why you choose to reassign name to name1 (which is a terribly unclear name - what's the point?). You then proceed to loop name over the characters in name1 (which suggests character would be a better name to use there) and since `name[index] < name1[index]` is always comparing the first character in the name to the same character, it's always `False`, so the loop always breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with the `index` and the comparison.

It seems like all you want to do is:

```
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']

for name in people:
    print(name)  # print the name
    for character in name:
        print(character, end=' ')  # print each character from the name
    print()  # print a line ending after the letters and spaces
```

Output:

```
Vianney
V i a n n e y 
Mariana
M a r i a n a 
Ignacio
I g n a c i o 
Gaspar
G a s p a r
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer to you too, very clear code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']
for name in people:
    print(name, '\n')
    for letter in name:
        print(letter, end =' ')
```

I have no idea what you really wanted and I was kinda surprised your code even ran.

If you don't want space at the end then,

```py
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']
for name in people:
    print(name, '\n')
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if i < len(name) - 1:
            print(name[i], end =' ')
        else:
            print(name[i])
```

or

```py
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']
for name in people:
    print(name, '\n')
    for i, letter in enumerate(name):
        if i < len(name) - 1:
            print(letter, end =' ')
        else:
            print(letter)
```

or

```py
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']
for name in people:
    print(name, '\n')
    print(" ".join(name))  # print(*name) also works but it'll only works with print and not when you want to store it as string.
```

or

```py
people = ['Vianney', 'Mariana', 'Ignacio', 'Gaspar']
print(f"{name}\n{' '.join(name)}" for name in people)
```

I strongly recommend the last 2 solutions

Comment: Thank you. All routines work very well and are very instructional.